# Help with Windows PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to access a method of text file, I use this first:

```
Get-Item file.txt | get-member
```

Then I would like to use the GetType() method, but it says it doesn't recognize file.txt as the name of a cmdlet,function,script file or operable problem. I need to access that or any other method :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of options here.  First is to turn the command into an expression by using parens:

```
(Get-Item file.txt).GetType()
```

The other option is to use Foreach-Object (aliased to foreach) in the  pipeline to execute arbitrary script against pipeline objects where each pipeline object is represented by the special variable `$_` e.g.:

```
Get-Item file.txt | Foreach {$_.GetType()}
```